# BeautifulSoup Unable to Parse Unexpected Encodings

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-3.3

Apologies in advance for this post if it's not well written as I'm extremely new to Python. Pretty simple/stupid problem I'm having with Python3 and BeautifulSoup. I'm attempting to parse a CSV file in Python without knowing what the encoding of each line will contain as each line contains raw data from several sources. Before I can even parse the file, I'm using BeautifulSoup in an attempt to clean it up (I'm not sure if this is a good idea):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open('files/sdk_breakout_1027.csv'))

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

When I run this, however, I encounter the following error:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 287: ordinal not in range(128)

My traceback points to this line in the CSV as the source of the problem:

> 500i(í£  : Android OS : 4.0.4

What is a better way to go about this? I just want to convert all rows in this CSV to a uniform encoding so I can parse it later.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is not for parsing CSV – you're right that this isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing the encoding of random data will never be perfect, but if you know something about your data source, you may be able to do that.

Alternatively, you can [open](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open) as UTF-8 and either ignore or replace errors:

```
import csv
with open("filename", encoding="utf8", errors="replace") as f:
  for row in csv.reader(f):
    print(", ".join(row))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Roger! This was extremely helpful and was able to give me the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse a CSV file with BeautifulSoup, only HTML or XML.

If you want to use the charset guessing from BeautifulSoup on its own, you can. See the [Unicode, Dammit](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit) section of the docs. If you have a complete list of all of the encodings that might have been used, but just don't know which one in that list was actually used, pass that list to Dammit.

There's a different charset-guessing library known as [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) that you also might want to try. (Note that Dammit will use chardet if you have it installed, so you might not need to try it separately.)

But both of these just make educated guesses; the documentation explains all the myriad ways they can fail.

Also, if each line is encoded differently (which is an even bigger mess than usual), you will have to Dammit or chardet each line as if it were a separate file. With much less text to work with, the guessing is going to be much less accurate, but there's nothing you can do about that if each line really is potentially in a different encoding.

Putting it all together, it would look something like this:

```
encodings = 'utf-8', 'latin-1', 'cp1252', 'shift-jis'

def dammitize(f):
    for line in f:
        yield UnicodeDammit(line, encodings).unicode_markup

with open('foo.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(dammitize(f)):
        do_something_with(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, abarnert! I was able to take a look at chardet to help clue me in on my own document.

Comment: @pyNovice89: Yeah, I should have mentioned that chardet also comes with a nifty command-line tool to help you guess manually. But thankfully, you figured it out on your own.